# Tweepy Error while collecting large number of data

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to get all the followers of a certain user on Twitter. Most of the users have more than 100k followers. My current code like below:

```
import tweepy
import time
from ttictoc import tic,toc


key1 = ""
key2 = ""
key3 = ""
key4 = ""

accountvar = ""

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(key1, key2)
auth.set_access_token(key3, key4)

tic()
#First, Make sure you have set wait_on_rate_limit to True while connecting through Tweepy
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True,wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)

#Below code will request for 5000 follower ids in one request and therefore will give 75K ids in every 15 minute window (as 15 requests could be made in each window).
followerids =[]
for user in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers_ids, screen_name=accountvar,count=5000).items():
    followerids.append(user)    
print (len(followerids))

#Below function could be used to make lookup requests for ids 100 at a time leading to 18K lookups in each 15 minute window
def get_usernames(userids, api):
    fullusers = []
    u_count = len(userids)
    print(u_count)
    try:
        for i in range(int(u_count/100) + 1):            
            end_loc = min((i + 1) * 100, u_count)
            fullusers.extend(
                api.lookup_users(user_ids=userids[i * 100:end_loc])                
            )
        return fullusers
    except:
        import traceback
        traceback.print_exc()
        print ('Something went wrong, quitting...')

#Calling the function below with the list of followeids and tweepy api connection details
fullusers = get_usernames(followerids,api)
print(toc())
```

Unfortunately, I am getting an error. I am using Python 3.8 in the Jupyter Notebook.

```
TweepError: Failed to send request: ('Connection aborted.', OSError("(10054, 'WSAECONNRESET')"))
```

Comment: WHERE did you get that error?  On which line of code, exactly?  ECONNRESET means the other end terminated the connection.

Comment: getting error after the first wait time. 
`for user in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers_ids, screen_name=accountvar,count=5000).items():
    followerids.append(user)    `

Comment: _after the first wait time_ -- I don't know what that means.  Are you getting a batch of 5,000 names?

Comment: sorry for the confusion. No after the batch of 75000 names. After getting the 75000 names, there is a wait time of 15 minutes because of the `wait_on_rate_limit = True`. I think because of the longer wait period the connection is getting disconnected.

Comment: Absolutely.  If nothing else, your local router/gateway probably times out idle connections after 5 or 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to the long wait time (15 minutes) after each 75,000 user data. The connection may times out because of the idle situation. Thanks to @Tim Roberts for his help.

One solution can be using a small enough sleep time `time.sleep(.02)` after collecting each follower_id and storing them in the list like the code snippet given below. So the connection does not need to wait for a long time. This way we can manage to keep the connection from disconnecting.

```
for user in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers_ids, screen_name=accountvar,count=5000).items():
        followerids.append(user)
        time.sleep(.02)
    print (len(followerids))
```